# Crash when building iOS app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build

We made an app in Unity for a client as following:

1. Little logo animation as start - works fine
2. Introduction video which starts automatically - works fine
3. Overview with START button - iPhone crashes
4. After the START there is supposed to be an overview with 4 mini games: one Augmented reality figure, 360 degrees video with VR glasses, VR shooting game with glasses and a simple memory game.

First we build the app in 32 bit, which worked fine. Apple only allows 64 bit in App Store, so we changed it. It still worked. Then Apple gave us this feedback:

Oct 3, 2017 at 4:02 PM
From Apple
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Thank you for your resubmission. After further review we found that your app still crashed on iPad running iOS 11.0.1 connected to an IPv6 network when we:

- Launch the app
- Skip the intro
- Tap on the start button
- App crashes

This occurred when your app was used:

- On Wi-Fi

We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure that it runs as expected.

---

Oct 4, 2017 at 2:59 PM
From jvandijk@ic-space.com (IC Space B.V.)
Dear Sir,
Thanks for quick update regarding issue in application.
As we submitted recent version for only iPhone as deployment target so can you please review it for iPhone only?
Or is there any specific step we need to follow to use this application only for iPhone.

Thanks
Angela

---

Oct 4, 2017 at 3:04 PM
From Apple
Hello Angela,

Thank you for your response.

Regarding the 2.1 issue, while we understand that your application is designed specifically for iPhone, we require all applications to run properly at iPhone resolution when viewed on iPad.

It would be appropriate to address this issue and make sure that your app displays and runs properly at iPhone resolution on iPad.

We are looking forward to reviewing your resubmission.

Best regards,

App Store Review

---

**So what we did change is:**

1. Put target device on iPhone Only and Architecture on Universal. 
   After that we got the crash and before all the games worked fine!

We run the crash report, but we do not see any problems.

I also check with iOS 10 apart from 11 and then I got the same issue, so it is something wrong in sources of unity I think.

Comment: 1.What Unity version? 2.Have your tired updating to the latest version?

Comment: Are you using network classes?

Comment: I do not use network classes. It is not latest Unity version, it is 2017.1.0f3